# How to set up a SSH tunnel and/or reverse SSH tunnel?

Tags: firefox, ssh, browser-addons, proxy, tunnel

I'm located in Shanghai China and am trying to set up an SSH tunnel (or a reverse ssh tunnel?) to my brother's server located in the States.  I'm using windows xp and he has a mac.  We are both using wireless routers (not sure if this is relevant).  He's given me the address and password (for his server, I think), and I've downloaded myentunnel (which he recommended), but am not sure what to do now.  I've also downloaded the foxyproxy add-on for mozilla (my preferred browser), and am hoping there is someone out there who can help guide a newbie like me!   Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I have never used MyEnTunnel, but I can recommend [Tunnelier](http://www.bitvise.com/tunnelier) that is also free and simple to use. After installing go to the Login page and enter the host address, username and password. Now go to Services and check Enabled under SOCKS, save the profile using the buttons to the left so that the settings are saved and click Login.

Now you need to configure Firefox (Mozilla is the developer), or more specifically Foxyproxy. Add a new proxy with the address 127.0.0.1 and port number 1080. Switch to using this proxy and all data to and from web sites should now be tunneled through your brothers Internet connection and it's all encrypted on the way there.

**However** DNS lookups may not be tunneled; this is very, very bad. Open up Firefox, type about:config in the address bar and then type network.proxy.socks_remote_dns in the filter field. Make sure the value is set to true, if it's false you should double click it and it will say true. Now you are all set!

Comment: Thank you for your help!  I uninstalled Myentunnel and installed Tunnelier as suggested.  Your instructions were very helpful and the installation went smoothly.  I also added the proxy with FoxyProxy and so far it looks good.  I had a slight problem - when I would turn the proxy on, I would get a message saying the proxy server was refusing connection. I talked to my brother and he's checking things on his end to see if there's a problem there.  I'll keep you updated on what happens. I just wanted to thank you for your help!!

Answer (score 1):

Well, I'm not sure how much easier this is, but this is what I did:

Generate a key:

```
ssh-keygen -t dsa
```

Put it on the server you connect to:

```
cat ~/.ssh/id_dsa.pub | ssh -l username ip.of.server 'cat >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys2'
```

You shouldn't need to enter a password when you log in.

---

To make it a quick-start thing, try this:

Start cygwin, and at the command line, type this:

```
echo '#!/bin/bash' >> /cygdrive/c/cygwin/goserv.h
echo 'ssh -ND 9999 user@server' >> /cygdrive/c/cygwin/goserv.sh
```

Look for your cygwin.bat file (it should be in your cygwin install directory, which on my machine, is c:\cygwin). Open it with Notepad, look for this line:

```
bash --login -i
```

and change it to this:

```
bash --login -i %1
```

Then save it. This won't hurt your normal use of cygwin. Now, create a new file in Notepad, and add this line:

```
c:\cygwin\cygwin.bat /cygdrive/c/cygwin/goserv.sh
```

Now save that as goserv.bat on your desktop. On my computer, double-clicking that file will create the tunnel.

As for Firefox - do you need to use it for non-tunnelled use? I use Chrome for regular use, and Firefox for tunnelled use. If you're really attached to Firefox, maybe you could install the [portable version](http://portableapps.com/apps/internet/firefox_portable) and leave that set up for proxy use.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be a foxyproxy-addon's problem, I'm not sure.
I'm using myentunnel,it's good enough.
In firefox, I installed AutoProxy, (http://autoproxy.org/en）， it can switch to your proxy by rules you've created.
I apologize for that as a Chinese, with ashame of my goverment's GFW policy.